# Problem setting conditions when adding to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want the following 3 conditions to be fulfilled :

1. Subscription product number 1 ( virtual ) ( in the cart ) +
   Subscription product number 2 ( virtual ) ( Add to cart ) = **NO**
2. Subscription product ( virtual ) ( in the cart ) + Simple product or variable ( virtual ) ( Add to cart ) = **NO**
3. Simple product or variable number 1 ( virtual ) ( in the cart ) + Simple product or variable number 2 ( virtual ) ( Add to cart ) = **YES**

I am using the following code :

```
if ( $cart_item['data']->is_virtual() && $is_virtual && $product->is_type( 'subscription' ) ) {
    wc_add_notice( __( '', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    return false;
}
```

I use `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` hook.

**Condition 1 and 3 are done correctly, but condition 2 is not done correctly.**

I am really confused, every time I make a change, one of the conditions is correct, but the other condition is wrong.

**Please take me out of this confusion.**

**UPDATE :** The point that I realized now, if we reverse option 2, the condition will be fulfilled, but if it remains the same, the condition will not be fulfilled. that's mean :

2. Simple product or variable ( virtual ) ( in the cart ) + Subscription product ( virtual ) ( Add to cart ) = **NO**